# Scala throwing the NullPointer Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running the below code to analyze data using Spark, I'm getting Nullpointer exception when executing the code.  There is an if (`uPopulation != null && !uPopulation.isEmpty()`) condition to filter the empty data but still getting the NullPointer Exception. Could any of you help me here?

```
package com.anil.wb
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.lang.Long

object WorldBankDataAnalysis {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\BigData\\Hadoop_setups\\hadoop- 
      2.5.0-cdh5.3.2")
    System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", 
   "file:/D:/BigData/Spark_setups/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-warehouse")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("UrbanPopulation").master("local").getOrCreate()

    val data = spark.read.csv("D:\\WorldBankAnalysis\\World_Bank_Indicators.csv").rdd

    val result = data.map { line =>
      val uPopulation = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",", "")
      var uPopNum = 0L
      if(uPopulation.length() > 0){
        uPopNum = Long.parseLong(uPopulation)
      }          
      (uPopNum, line.getString(0))
    }
    .sortByKey(false)

    //spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(result)).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
    result.foreach { println }
    spark.stop
  }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
Afghanistan,7/1/2000,0,,0,,151,11,8,"25,950,816","5,527,524",51,45,45,45,48,50,2    
Afghanistan,7/1/2001,0,,0,0,150,11,9,"26,697,430","5,771,984",50,46,45,46,48,50,2,"2,461,666,315",92
Afghanistan,7/1/2002,0,,"25,000",0,150,22,7,"27,465,525","6,025,936",49,46,46,46,48,50,2,"4,338,907,579",158    
Afghanistan,7/1/2003,0,,"200,000",0,151,25,8,"28,255,719","6,289,723",48,46,46,46,48,50,2,"4,766,127,272",169    
Afghanistan,7/1/2004,0,,"600,000",0,150,30,9,"29,068,646","6,563,700",47,46,46,46,48,50,2,"5,704,202,651",196    
Afghanistan,7/1/2005,0,,"1,200,000",1,151,33,9,"29,904,962","6,848,236",47,47,47,47,48,50,2,"6,814,753,581",228    
Afghanistan,7/1/2006,0,11,"2,520,366",2,151,24,7,"30,751,661","7,158,987",46,47,47,47,48,50,2,"7,721,931,671",251    
Afghanistan,7/1/2007,0,18,"4,668,096",2,150,29,7,"31,622,333","7,481,844",45,47,47,47,47,50,2,"9,707,373,721",307    
Afghanistan,7/1/2008,0,19,"7,898,909",2,150,32,7,"32,517,656","7,817,245",45,48,47,48,47,51,2,"11,940,296,131",367    
Afghanistan,7/1/2009,0,21,"12,000,000",3,149,34,8,"33,438,329","8,165,640",44,48,48,48,47,51,2,"14,213,670,485",425    
Afghanistan,7/1/2010,0,,"13,000,000",4,149,38,8,"34,385,068","8,527,497",44,48,48,48,46,51,2,"17,243,112,604",501
```

Output to be as 0th and 10th String values:

```
8527497 Afghanistan
8165640 Afghanistan
7817245 Afghanistan
5527524 Afghanistan
```

Note 10th String value is empty for some countries.

Comment: If i write the code data.collect it works fine. I'm running the code on local mode, so there is no problem in reading the file.

Comment: @vindev Agree with you, please can you help me in tweaking the code so to filter out if any null values.

Comment: did you track which line is throwing nullpointer? and what do you mean by when you do collect it works

Comment: @RameshMaharjan val uPopulation = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",", "") is the line throwing the nullpointer exception.

Comment: youu didn't answer my second question about collect

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Sorry I couldn't answer you yesterday as I was not having the development environment with me. So what I mean is, when I try to print data present in the rdd data.foreach { println }  (not data.collect()) it works fine. Data will get printed on the console which means program is successful in reading the data from the CSV file. Only issue I have is line.getString(10) is NULL for some countries which is causing the program to throw NULLPointer Exception. I've attached some Sample Data.

Comment: Alexey has already answered your query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df=spark.read.csv("D:\\WorldBankAnalysis\\World_Bank_Indicators.csv")
val extractNum=udf((s:String) => s.replace(",","").toLong)
newDf=df.select(extractNum($"_c10").alias("population"),$"_c0".alias("country"))
newDf.show()
```

Comment: Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz,  Sample data at line.getString(0) = Canada, line.getString(10) = "542,383,99". Yes, i agree with you spark.read.csv would parse the CSV file with the default separator (',').  All I need on the result(rdd) is  54238399, Canada. 59268399, USA etc.. Does this make sense? Note: line.getString(10) will have empty data as well.

Comment: If you'd add some sample data tot the q it would be easier to see exactly what the problem is

Comment: Added the sample data: Output to be as 0th and 10th String values. : 8527497 Afghanistan 8165640 Afghanistan 7817245 Afghanistan 5527524 Afghanistan- sortByKey(false)
Note 10th String value is empty for some countries so on...

Comment: Thanks Arnon your solution worked fine. I found a way to solve this without using dataframe . I've upvoted your answer.                                                 val result = data.map { line => {
    var uPopNum = 0L
    if(line.isNullAt(10)){
      uPopNum=0
    }else{
       val uPopulation = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",", "")
       if (uPopulation.length() > 0)
       uPopNum = Long.parseLong(uPopulation)
   }
     (uPopNum,line.getString(0))
    }
     }

Comment: why don't you want to use a dataframe- you get it anyway when you use spark.read.csv

Answer (score 0):

My guess given this code is that `line.getString(10)` is null for *some* line. So `val uPopulation = ...` throws `NullPointerException` and you never get to the `uPopulation != null` check (which is useless because `replaceAll` never returns null).

As Ramesh's comment mentions, you should start by looking at what line the exception is reported in: if the above theory is correct, that should be the `val uPopulation = ...` one.

Comment: You're right Alexey,  val uPopulation = line.getString(10).replaceAll(",", "") line is throwing the NullPointer Exception.